# Find the same and replace it

Tags: oracle

There are 2 tables:

[image: author]

[image: holding]

Now I want to query the title of the author table for the same value as the barcode field in the holding table. Then? Add the value of Auth in author to callNo in holding .

This is what I wrote:

```
update holding h set 
  h.CALLNO = (select a.author 
              from AUTHOR a 
              where a.TITLE = h.BARCODE)
```

This statement is wrong, it transformed my column into null.

Comment: Within your screenshots I see no `a.title` equal to `h.barcode`. Therefore, your query `(select a.author from AUTHOR a where a.TITLE=h.BARCODE)` always returns `null`. In other words, it's not your statement that is wrong but your data is different from what you expect.

Comment: Agreed. Statement is correct, data is not what you think it is. Do you have any records in `AUTHOR` that have a `TITLE` equal to a `BARCODE` in `holding`? If you do and it's still showing up NULL after running this, then you may have some whitespace after either your `BARCODE` or `author` values.